# Scoping sass variable

Tags: css, sass, scope

Is there a way to add scope to sass variables?

I want to be able to attach a class to my `body` element. The class will refer to a set of colours that the rest of the stylesheets can access.

I have tried:

```
@mixin theme_one{
    $color: #000;
}
.theme_one{
  @include theme_one;
}
```

and

```
.theme_one{

  $color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Just so I am clear. You have the class .theme_one on your body tag right? And if that class is there you will then replace all of the colors in your document defined by that class. Is this correct?

Comment: yeah. I'd then like to load that class dynamically in order to change the theme

Comment: Okay one more question then. Are you only changing the "color" property?

Comment: nope, colour values of several rules (borders, backgrounds etc)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770603/set-scss-variables-based-on-element-scopes can you help with this?

Answer (score 3):

I've just come across the same issue myself. I wanted to have different colour themes for different sections of my site.

Using a mixin seems like the best way to go. It's nicely DRY, and easy to use. The trick is not setting your colours in your main styles blocks, but rather using only the mixin for this.

I've set up the theme colours as variables at the top so they can be edited nicely, and I've set them as lists so that multiple values can be passed without hordes of variable being defined.

So:

```
// Variable Definitions

$defaultColor: black white grey;
$color2:       blue green brown;
$color3:       red white blue;

@mixin colorSet($color: $defaultColor) {
  $link:       nth($color, 1);
  $border:     nth($color, 2);
  $background: nth($color, 3);

  border-color: $border;
  background-color: $background;

  .column {
    border-color: lighten($border, 10%);
  }

  a {
    color: $link;
    &:hover {
      color: darken($link, 15%);
    }
  }

}

// Default colours
body {
  @include colorSet();
}

// Scoped colours
.my-theme-3 {
  @include colorSet($color3);
}

.my-theme-2 {
  @include colorSet($color2);
}
```

Will produce something like this:

```
body {
  border-color: white;
  background-color: grey; }
  body .column {
    border-color: white; }
  body a {
    color: black; }
    body a:hover {
      color: black; }

.my-theme-3 {
  border-color: white;
  background-color: blue; }
  .my-theme-3 .column {
    border-color: white; }
  .my-theme-3 a {
    color: red; }
    .my-theme-3 a:hover {
      color: #b30000; }

.my-theme-2 {
  border-color: green;
  background-color: brown; }
  .my-theme-2 .column {
    border-color: #00b300; }
  .my-theme-2 a {
    color: blue; }
    .my-theme-2 a:hover {
      color: #0000b3; }
```

Edit: Updated to use default mixin values.

Comment: excellent answer just what I was looking for thanks. I'd mark as answer for OP if i could ;)

Comment: I am not able to get the variables inside the mixin to work for the other parts of the app?

Comment: help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770603/set-scss-variables-based-on-element-scopes

Answer (score 0):

In your case no need to use mixin, If you have set of many styles then use mixin, 
ie. if you have

```
@mixin theme_one{
    $color: #000;
    height: 50px;
}
```

then use Mixin

otherwise for single property use only variable

```
$color: #fff;


.some_class01{

  color: $color;
  background: $color;
}

.some_class22{
  border-color: $color;
}
```

IMP: Variable should assign at the top of your code, it means don't use it after/below where you assigned it :)

Comment: This is too long winded to go through my whole stylesheet adding class to each colour rule. Much easier is to assign scope to the variables based on the existence of a parent class.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for. It looks like you may have tried something similar to this,
which should probably work. (it may just be a matter of using !default)

Your body tag with a class on it..

```
<body class="theme_one">

</body>
```

Sass variables defined in stylesheet..

```
//THEME ONE VARIABLES
.theme_one{
    $borderColor:#333 !default;
    $fontColor:#999 !default;
}

//THEME TWO VARIABLES
.theme_two{
    $borderColor:#CCC !default;
    $fontColor:#000 !default;
}
```

Pre-existing CSS which will be overwritten depending on which class is used on the body tag.

```
h1.someheader {
    color:$fontColor;
    border-bottom:1px solid;
    border-color:$borderColor;
}
```

Otherwise you could maybe try something like this. It looks like you may have tried something similar, however there seems to be an error with your mixin ... see note below.

```
//mixin used to set variables for properties
@mixin themeOne($fontColor,$borderColor) {
    color:$fontColor;
    border-color:$borderColor;
}

@include themeOne(#000,#CCC);
```

Pre-existing CSS

```
h1.someheader {
    color:$fontColor
    border-color:$borderColor;
    border-bottom:1px solid;
}
```

Also note in your mixin example you are using `$color:#000;` ... This won't be interpreited properly as it should be color:#000; You can't use variables as selectors
unless you do something like `#{$color}:#000;`

I haven't quite tested this yet, so some things might need to be adjusted. If this doesn't solve your problem I hope it at least gives you some ideas.